# Vuetify v-navigation-drawer mini-variant width

Tags: css, vuetify.js, v-navigation-drawer

Whilest you can set the width of the of the unfolded drawer like this

```
<v-navigation-drawer ... width="250">
```

How can i set the wisth for the collapsed mini-variant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the lastest vuetify version, you can use the prop `mini-variant-width` to set the width for the mini variant. (default 56px)

```html
<v-navigation-drawer
   v-model="drawer"
   :mini-variant.sync="mini"
   mini-variant-width="80px"
   permanent
>
  ...
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-navigation-drawer/#props-mini-variant-width